# WCF service hosted in IIS is starting and stopping for each call

Tags: performance, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS 7.

When I installed it on my server I created a new site, application and application pool in IIS. I then discovered that my client seemed to be very slow, but it turned out that the wcf service started and stopped every time the client made a call to it.
While debugging this I saw that another application pool on my server was set up in the same way as the one I had created, so I set my site to use this one instead. Everything worked fine, and after searching for a reason without success I decided not to spend more time on this.

This was all on my test server.  When it was time to take my application to prod I copied the application pool from my test server and pasted in to prod, using

- appcmd list apppool  /config  /xml > C:\apppools.xml
- appcmd add apppool   /in  < C:\apppools.xml

I also copied the sites:

- appcmd list site  /config  /xml > C:\sites.xml
- appcmd add siteg  /in  < C:\sites.xml

But then I had the same issue as on the test server, the wcf service starting and stopping all the time, causing the client application to appear very slow.

I've tried searching for differences between the servers, app pools, sites etc, but nothing I've tried has brought me to a solution

If anyone has a suggestion on how to solve this is would be highly appreciated!